# Angular karma-jasmine failing for pipe DatePipe

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am using Angular2 and having parent child components. My child component is using DatePipe provider due to which parent unit test is failing and giving below error,

Error: Illegal state: Could not load the summary for pipe DatePipe.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** Resolved the issue. I was adding DatePipe as provider in my child component that's no more needed. Don't need to inject pipes. Use the underlying function of the pipe directly instead. All the Angular ones are public now.

```
//Just import DatePipe
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';

//In class definition create the instance of the DatePipe
datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');

// And just call the transform method
console.log(this.datePipe.transform(dateValue, 'MM/dd/yyyy'));
```